# AMD GPU fan not working and can't sense temperature

Tags: drivers, fan, temperature, amdgpu

I assembled a new desktop with a Radeon RX5700 GPU and an Ubuntu 18.04 system. The GPU fan only spins when I boot the computer, and then stops. Using sensors command reports error:

```
$ sensors
amdgpu-pci-2f00
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:       +0.78 V  
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature fan1_input: I/O error
fan1:             N/A  (min =    0 RPM, max = 3600 RPM)
edge:             N/A  (crit = +118.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (emerg = +80000.0°C)
junction:         N/A  (crit = +80000.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (emerg = +80000.0°C)
mem:              N/A  (crit = +80000.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (emerg = +80000.0°C)
power1:        8.00 W  (cap = 160.00 W)
```

I am not sure what goes wrong here. Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: If you have Windows, please test with Windows in order to rule out a hardware error. If not, does the fan spin when you boot from a LiveUSB? Please advise.

Comment: I think that problem is in values, 80000°C. It is causing global warming.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to get fan speed. fancontrol utility works very good without any current fanspeed info. You can install via

```
sudo apt-get install fancontrol
```

My fancontrol config in /etc/fancontrol :

```
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon2=devices/platform/it87.2608 hwmon3=devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
DEVNAME=hwmon2=it8728 hwmon3=amdgpu
FCTEMPS=hwmon3/pwm1=hwmon3/temp1_input
FCFANS=hwmon3/pwm1=hwmon2/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon3/pwm1=60
MAXTEMP=hwmon3/pwm1=100
MINSTART=hwmon3/pwm1=60
MINSTOP=hwmon3/pwm1=20
MINPWM=hwmon3/pwm1=0
MAXPWM=hwmon3/pwm1=255
```

My case resonates at some frequencies so I have written a python script to jump that frequencies (Fan RPMS). It works very well for me. I run it on top of fan control ... if it somehow fails fancontrol takes over ... Thats why time.sleep is 0.25 second if any longer fan control kicks in ...

My python script :

```
import os,time
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE

os.system('echo auto > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level')

keepcooling=False
while True:
    time.sleep(0.25)
    with Popen(["cat","/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_input"], stdout=PIPE) as proc:
        fantemp=int(proc.stdout.read().decode('ascii'))

    temp=fantemp/1000

    if temp <=45:
        fanpwm=0

    if temp >45 and temp <= 75: 
        fanpwm=temp

    if (temp >75 ) and (temp <=95):
        fanpwm=temp+55

    if temp>95: 
        fanpwm=200
        keepcooling=True; #cool until 80C reached

    if temp>=100: 
        os.system('reboot')

    if temp<=80:
        keepcooling=False

    if keepcooling and temp > 80:
        fanpwm=200



    print('temp',temp,'fanpwm',int(fanpwm)) 
    os.system('echo '+str(int(fanpwm))+' > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1')
   # print('echo '+str(int(fanpwm))+' > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1')
```

Be careful adjust and test many times if you want to use it.
You can monitor things via lm-sensors and psensor ...
and fan speed via

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1
```